# Error while compiling Solidity contract with OpenZeppelin's ERC721Enumerable.sol

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle, openzeppelin

I'm currently working on a Solidity smart contract that makes use of the ERC721Enumerable extension from OpenZeppelin. However, when I attempt to compile using Truffle, I encounter a ParserError.

Here's the relevant part of my contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";

contract Degree is ERC721Enumerable {
    // ... (contract details)
}
```

When I try to compile using truffle compile, I get the following error:

```
@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol:14:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
abstract contract ERC721Enumerable is ERC721, IERC721Enumerable {
^------^
```

Compilation failed. See above.

Any ideas what could be causing this error and how I can resolve it?

I tried these:

Verifying the path to the imported OpenZeppelin contract.
Checking the ERC721Enumerable.sol file directly to see if there's anything unusual at the specified line.

Comment: Can you change your solidity pragma to: `pragma solidity ^0.8.0;` and check if its fine? There are plenty of breaking changes between `0.4` and `0.8`.

Comment: Provide your code